# .Trim() Method not working? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, trim

I'm looping through elements in a string array to find and remove vowels, yet it only removes the 'o' from the first element.

What i have:

```
string[] inst = new string[] { "cello", "guitar", "violin", "double bass", };

        for(int x = 0; x < inst.Length; x++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(inst[x].Trim(new Char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' }));

        }
```

Output:
[image: Compiler Output]

Comment: [`Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx) only removes from the start and end of a string.

Comment: Why would trim work in this instance? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: before ask this question, you should search `Trim` function in msdn

Comment: A very cursory glance at the readily available documentation would have saved you some time. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx

Comment: I took a very, very cursory glance lol. Obvious too cursory, I thought that it trimmed the entire string. Forgive my ignorance, thanks for the support anyway.

Answer (score 4):

That's expected behaviour. Trim() removes specified characters from the begging and end of the string:

> The Trim method removes from the current string all leading and
>   trailing white-space characters. Each leading and trailing trim
>   operation stops when a non-white-space character is encountered. For
>   example, if the current string is "   abc   xyz   ", the Trim method
>   returns "abc   xyz".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `Trim` method only removes characters from the beginning and end of a `String`, as the documentation says.  It doesn't remove characters from the middle.  You might want `String.Replace` for that, replacing single-character substrings with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `Replace()` method, not the `Trim()`

```
for(int x = 0; x < inst.Length; x++)
    {

        inst[x] = inst[x].Replace("a", "");
        inst[x] = inst[x].Replace("e", "");
        inst[x] = inst[x].Replace("i", "");
        inst[x] = inst[x].Replace("o", "");
        inst[x] = inst[x].Replace("u", "");
    }
```